# How to fix dual-boot installation of Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Win7?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 Ultimate and completely messed up. I downloaded the file and burned a CD. Got confused with the partitioning because I wanted to install it in my Drive D once my drive C is a Corsair Force GT ATA Device, 120Gb and has only 39GB free. The Drive D is 2TB and is completely empty. I had created 2 partitions in the Drive D both 500Gb big and the remaining 800Gb were not partitioned. After the installation I got a 19Gb partition that seems to be equally empty. I cannot at all see where Ubuntu is installed because I cannot identify any file. If I boot from the installation CD, it says that Ubuntu 14.04 is already installed - but Where?
I ordered a new CD from Canonical. Does it contain an uninstall program? Is it actually possible to install in a second disk (Drive D)? If so Can I make the second disk bootable so that I can start it from BIOS without touching Windows? The computer is high-end and very powerful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you boot into Ubuntu? If you can, then open the program called Disks. Check the disk partitions and try to identify which is the partition where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: Drives in Linux do not have a drive letter (C:, D:) but are designated like sda, sdb, etc. sda is the 1st disk, sdb the second etc. partitions on the 1st disk would be sda1, sda2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1) Most probably you have installed Ubuntu just fine, and it's on your 2nd disk's 1st partition, but your BIOS settings make your computer boot from the 1st disk, where Windows is installed, and you naturally can't see the contents of your Ubuntu partition there (Windows can't see Ubuntu, but Ubuntu can see Windows ;-)

2) This setup is actually very good for your purposes, as you can now change the BIOS Boot Settings and give your second disk (where Ubuntu is installed) first priority, and choose Ubuntu or Windows every time you boot your computer, or revert back to the previous BIOS boot priority to boot directly to Windows when you want it, and so on.

You need to press a key like F2, F10, F12 or Esc (which varies with different computer brands and models) at the black screen that appears immediately after pressing the power button to enter into BIOS Boot Priority Settings menu.

Answer (score -1):

Windows7 use NTFS Filesystem but Ubuntu use Ext4 Filesystem, and you can mount NTFS in Ubuntu, but win7 can't recongnise Ext4,that all

Comment: there is no such a uninstall program, just delete the partion, boot computer to win7 and download a software named 'easybcd', follow the guid